# Xamarin MainPage error: name doesn't exist in the current context

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've got a label in my MainPage.xml with the name 'txtInhoud', but when I try to set the text of it in my MainPage.xml.cs (`txtInhoud.Text =` […]), I get the error that the name doesn't exist in the current context.

I've tried rebuilding the project and deleting the bin and obj files, but that didn't work.

Any help?

Comment: is the `Label` inside of a template?

Comment: What do you mean by that? It is inside of the swipeCardView of https://github.com/markolazic88/SwipeCardView

Comment: that `Label` is **clearly** inside of a `DataTemplate`.  You cannot reference items inside a template by name.  You should use databinding to set the properties of templated elements.

Answer (score 0):

From sample code , the `Label` is inside `DataTemplate` . We can not `get` or `set` Text by `x:Name = "txtInhoud"` , because it has been binded with `ItemsSource` .

```
<swipeCardView:SwipeCardView
    ItemsSource="{Binding CardItems}"
    SwipedCommand="{Binding SwipedCommand}"
    LoopCards="{Binding IsLoopCards}"
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <swipeCardView:SwipeCardView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label x:Name="txtInhoud" Text="{Binding .}" FontSize="Large" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="Beige" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </swipeCardView:SwipeCardView.ItemTemplate>
</swipeCardView:SwipeCardView>
```

You can see that `swipeCardView:SwipeCardView` has binded `ItemsSource="{Binding CardItems}"` , and this ContentPage has `BindingContext = new SimplePageViewModel();`.

Then the text of `Label` is designed from `SimplePageViewModel` .

```
public class SimplePageViewModel : BasePageViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> _cardItems;
    private bool _isLoopCards;
    private string _message;

    public SimplePageViewModel()
    {
        _cardItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            _cardItems.Add($"Card {i}");
        }
        _isLoopCards = true;
        SwipedCommand = new Command<SwipedCardEventArgs>(OnSwipedCommand);

        ClearItemsCommand = new Command(OnClearItemsCommand);
        AddItemsCommand = new Command(OnAddItemsCommand);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> CardItems
    {
        get => _cardItems;
        set
        {
            _cardItems = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
...
}
```

From above code , you will see the `CardItems` add five `string` element .Due to `Label` bind text with `Text="{Binding .}"` , then the `Text` of each `Label` is the CardItems's each `string` element .

In addition , we can add a customed `Name` property for each Item in ViewModel . For example , modify `CardItems` as follow :

```
 ...
    private ObservableCollection<CardItem> _cardItems;
    private bool _isLoopCards;
    private string _message;

    public SimplePageViewModel()
    {
        _cardItems = new ObservableCollection<CardItem>();
        for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            _cardItems.Add(new CardItem() { Name = $"Custom Card {i}" });
        }

        _cardItems[0].Name = "This is the first Card Item";

        _isLoopCards = true;
        SwipedCommand = new Command<SwipedCardEventArgs>(OnSwipedCommand);

        ClearItemsCommand = new Command(OnClearItemsCommand);
        AddItemsCommand = new Command(OnAddItemsCommand);
    }
 ...
```

The `CardItem` is defined as follow :

```
public class CardItem
{
    public string Name { set; get; }
}
```

**Xaml** also need to modidy the `Text` binded key with : `<Label Text="{Binding Name}" ...`

Now the effect :

[image]